# command pattern

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

подскажите может ли быть несколько receiver'ов в command-pattern'е? реализую простой клиент для dropbox'са, получается несколько команд (код ниже) уместен ли здесь вышеуказанный паттрен? Конкретней, есть методы getAuth(), helper() .... правильно ли будет создать отдельные классы (receiver) или сделать один с соответствующими методам concret-commandam'и?

```
 private void command(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, DbxException {

    while (true) {

        if (args.length == 0){
            args = helper();
        } else if (args[0].toLowerCase().equals("auth") && args.length == 3){
            getAuth(args);
            break;
        } else if (args[0].toLowerCase().equals("info") && args.length > 1 && args.length < 4) {
            getInfo(args);
            break;
        } else if (args[0].toLowerCase().equals("list") && args.length > 2 && args.length < 5){
            getList(args);
            break;
        } else {
            args = helper();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Данный паттерн обычно применяется когда есть некая очередность комманд и нужно хранить историю выполнения комманд, для отката на 1-N шагов назад. А также потом если необходимо для перехода на 1-N шагов вперед.

В вашем случае не понимаю почему был выбран именно данный паттерн...вы собираетесь создавать историю выполнения комманд? (с возможностью отката?)

Вы лучше изложите задачу подробей, что будут за методы и какой функционал нести, тогда можно будет посоветовать чтото более конкретное...

Comment: спс , похоже мне этот паттерн в данной задаче не нужен )

Answer (score 1):

Данный паттерн обычно применяется когда есть некая очередность комманд и нужно хранить историю выполнения комманд, для отката на 1-N шагов назад. А также потом если необходимо для перехода на 1-N шагов вперед.

В вашем случае не понимаю почему был выбран именно данный паттерн...вы собираетесь создавать историю выполнения комманд? (с возможностью отката?)

Вы лучше изложите задачу подробей, что будут за методы и какой функционал нести, тогда можно будет посоветовать чтото более конкретное...